# Подскажите, почему возвращает None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

Подскажите,почему возвращает `None`?

Задача: Дан список, ввести число, если оно есть в списке, то вывести индекс. Решить рекурсией

```
k = [1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
l = int(input('input number'))


def search(v,w):
    if len(v) < 1:
        return 'not position'
    else:
        for i in range(len(v) // 2):
            if w == v[i]:
                return i
        search(v[len(v)//2:],w)


print(search(k,l))
```

Comment: Если коротко: перед `search(v[len(v)//2:],w)` должен быть `return`.

Answer (score 2):

Я решил бы это таким образом:

```
In [16]: array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

In [17]: def binary_search(array, value, start, stop):
    ...:     if start > stop:
    ...:         return False
    ...:     middle = (start + stop) // 2
    ...:     if value == array[middle]:
    ...:         return middle
    ...:     if value > array[middle]:
    ...:         return binary_search(array, value, middle + 1, stop)
    ...:     return binary_search(array, value, start, middle - 1)
    ...:
```

Результат:

```
In [18]: binary_search(array, 5, 0, len(array)-1)
Out[18]: 4

In [19]: binary_search(array, 10, 0, len(array)-1)
Out[19]: False
```

Ваш код не рабочий потому что перед `search(v[len(v)//2:],w)` нужно добавить `return`. Но если ввести число которого нет в списке, Вы получите исключение:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Потому что длина списка у Вас никогда не будет `< 1` .

Comment: Спасибо большое, гениально и просто=)